# Getting Exception while executing the Hive Create Table statement

Tags: hive

I am getting the "SemanticException [Error 10002]: Invalid column reference" while executing the below statement.
`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS default.employee_details_3(FirstName VARCHAR(20),LastName VARCHAR(20)) COMMENT 'This is a test table mod'  PARTITIONED BY(Emp_id INT,Gender VARCHAR(15),EmailAddress VARCHAR(40))  CLUSTERED BY(Emp_id,Gender,EmailAddress) INTO 14 BUCKETS  ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' STORED AS SEQUENCEFILE ;`

I have used the following link for reference
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because you are doing partitioning and bucketing on the same column. You can not use same column in partitioned by as well clustered by clause.
use different columns, it will work.
Try below query :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS default.employee_details_3
(FirstName VARCHAR(20),
LastName VARCHAR(20)) COMMENT 'This is a test table mod' 
PARTITIONED BY(Emp_id INT,Gender VARCHAR(15),EmailAddress VARCHAR(40)) 
CLUSTERED BY(FirstName) INTO 14 BUCKETS 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' STORED AS SEQUENCEFILE ;
```